# C# Data grid view not registering key presses

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a winform with a data grid view control in it. At one point I was able to use the up and down arrows to navigate the rows in the grid view and the form captured user key presses to allow our admins to enter a code to get into the administration panel.

Now for some reason the datagridview won't register key presses and the form_KeyDown event isn't firing when any key is pressed.

None of the key events of the grid view are overridden and the KeyPreview property of the form is set to true.

What else do I need to check or change to get the data grid view to register keys?

Edit I can't think of any actual code that is relevant. This is the only event that handles key presses. But this event isn't firing.

```
this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.frm1_KeyDown); 

 private void frm1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //omitted
    }
```

Like I said, there is no code handling key presses other than this, and it isn't firing.

Here is the keydown event code

And here is the generated code for the data grid view

```
// 
        // dgvMachines
        // 
        this.dgvMachines.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.dgvMachines.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this.dgvMachines.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
        this.dgvMachines.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
        this.dgvMachines.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.dgvMachines.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        this.dgvMachines.AutoSizeRowsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
        this.dgvMachines.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle2;
        this.dgvMachines.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dgvMachines.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.clmDomain,
        this.clmMachineName,
        this.ClmMachineDescription,
        this.clmRDPName,
        this.clmRDPPassword,
        this.ClmUserName,
        this.ClmLoginTime,
        this.clmStatus,
        this.clmIPAddress,
        this.clmID,
        this.clmSourceHostName});
        this.dgvMachines.DataSource = this.bsMachineDGRow;
        dataGridViewCellStyle8.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        dataGridViewCellStyle8.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
        dataGridViewCellStyle8.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        dataGridViewCellStyle8.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
        dataGridViewCellStyle8.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
        dataGridViewCellStyle8.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
        dataGridViewCellStyle8.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.False;
        this.dgvMachines.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle8;
        this.dgvMachines.EditMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnF2;
        this.dgvMachines.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 65);
        this.dgvMachines.MultiSelect = false;
        this.dgvMachines.Name = "dgvMachines";
        dataGridViewCellStyle9.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        dataGridViewCellStyle9.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
        dataGridViewCellStyle9.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        dataGridViewCellStyle9.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
        dataGridViewCellStyle9.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
        dataGridViewCellStyle9.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
        dataGridViewCellStyle9.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
        this.dgvMachines.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle9;
        this.dgvMachines.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        this.dgvMachines.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        this.dgvMachines.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(753, 510);
        this.dgvMachines.TabIndex = 28;
        this.dgvMachines.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dgvMachines_CellClick);
        this.dgvMachines.CellDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dgvMachines_CellDoubleClick);
        this.dgvMachines.RowEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dgvMachines_RowEnter);
        this.dgvMachines.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.dgvMachines_MouseDown);
```

Comment: provide your code,without some code we can't help you.

Comment: Is the event properly bound to the control? Please send code concerning your control from your Form Designer

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `KeyPreview` property to false in the form. The datagridview is capable of handle arrow keys itself.

Another propertiy that can cause problems is `SelectionMode`: you can't navigate across cells if is set to `FullRowSelect`.

If you need the user enter a code, provide a textBox to enter the code there and then perform de search

Comment: Changing that property didn't resolve the issue. And I don't need to navigate across cells, just up and down rows.
I have the form handling the code input so that no matter what control has focus the code will still work.